How are these answers to "What's your biggest weakness"?
I am preparing for an interview for an IT researcher position at a large company. One common interview question that I am somewhat afraid of is "What are your weaknesses?" or variations thereof. Possible answers I am thinking about are:

As an introvert, I tend to focus on my work rather than communication with colleagues.
I am very bad at selling stuff.
I tend to dive too deep into details.
I cannot leave hold of my work, at weekends or in the evening, I often find myself researching work-related topics.
I cannot say "no" to anything, try to please everyone

What do these options imply to an interviewer? What makes them suitable or unsuitable for an answer for this position?

As an interviewer, each of those answers screams to me "this is some stuff I made up because I think it sounds good" and tells me you're probably lying. Which of those weaknesses do you actually have?

I talk too less to people and don't engage much in conversations. This is a common criticism I've got in performance reviews. But this is a quite severe weakness, isn't it?

So explain what you're doing to improve. You are doing something to improve, right?

This question is similar to: How are tough introspective or behavioural type interview questions assessed?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@PhilipKendall: Does anyone really think #2, #4 or #5 sound good? I'd rather be worried the OP is "way too honest" with them and risks putting some big "has serious issues - do not hire" signs on their profile.

@O.R.Mapper I wouldn't say so, but they show up on lists like this one...

My favorite answer that I've ever read to this bad question (obviously don't actually use it): "My biggest weakness is feeling crushed under the staggering weight of all my strengths"

@PlayerOne I like "I find it difficult not to express my true feelings when interviewers are using lazy questions"

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2278/102

https://youtu.be/rG6w0IAoT4U?t=47

My favorite: "My biggest weakness is that I'm always honest" - Interviewer: "Well, I don't think that is a weakness...?" - Answer: "I don't give a sh*t what you think!"

Its a BS question expecting BS answers. So in the end any BS will do just fine.

Never understood the point of this question - you're almost guaranteed to get a BS answer. Unless it's to screen out the individuals stupid enough to answer honestly.


"What are your weaknesses?"

You have to realise that these questions are not scientifically chosen for the profound answers they solicit, they're just idle small talk that interviewers make (most of whom have little or no skill in discerning the recruits which the company actually requires), and one good cliche deserves another.
Most strengths have their corresponding weaknesses. For example, those who hold themselves to high standards may be neurotic and narky. Those who work too hard are liable to burn out.
The trick with a question like this is to find something about yourself that is a mild weakness, but is also the kind of weakness that the employer would consider par for the course in your occupation.
For example, if you're an introvert applying for a routine clerical job, then you can say sometimes you're a little too quiet. But you don't want to say that if you're applying for a job in sales.

This is a BS interview question for the most part IMHO. It is highly subjective by most interviewers.
The most meaningful response is something that shows that you are "Self-Aware" and are not perfect.
At my company we look for someone that answers this question alongs the lines of ensuring that they won't burn-out or that they understand that continious improvement is important. That is us, your results might be different.


As an introvert, I tend to focus on my work rather than communication with colleagues.
I am very bad at selling stuff.

I like these two.  In my opinion you do have to point out an actual weakness.  This shows self reflection, humility, and the jobs you are not suitable for.
My favorite:
I am poor at making technical decisions under pressure.
I will not perform well being part of a tech support team.  While I am a senior dev, having me respond to crisis updates will not go well.

My Tactic has always been to pick a strength - and talk about it as a Weakness.
One example is that I am not a Yes Man, if I think that Management is doing a BS idea, I will have no problem telling them in no uncertain (but polite and professional) terms.
I let them know that for some managers, this rubs them the wrong way - but then I point out that with experience I have learned when to raise these issues - and Managers who listen to me and take my issues onboard and works collaboratively is the best.

I probably wouldn't ask this question, but I have some idea what I would want to get out of this question.
What I am looking for in candidates is the potential to grow. Part of this is self-awareness about ones weaknesses and willingness to overcome them.
So the first question

What are your weaknesses?

Would set up this line of questioning. The actual answer isn't that important, I'd only pay attention if it is a real weakness or some fake weakness, "I work too hard", "I'm too perfect".
If I get the feeling that someone is bullshitting I would drill deep to expose the BS.
After we established the context, my follow up would be what the candidate is actively doing to understand the weakness better and improve on it.
E.g. if the candidates weakness is that they don't talk enough to other people then I ask, how they know about the weakness. If they have actively asked their peers about ways to improve it, and what concrete steps they have done to talk more to people.
Generally someone who thinks they are perfect in their current role and have no real improvement points, is a big red flag to me.
So to prepare to this line of question I suggest the following:

Ask your peers and managers about the biggest weaknesses that are holding you back on having a bigger impact
Reflect on the answers and choose one or two problem areas you want to focus on
Discuss with your manager some idea how to improve and create plan to address that weakness
Execute that plan

If your manager in your current org isn't willing to help you (quite possible since you are looking for a new job), you have to do it without them. But you should try to include them anyways.
After you have done all these things, you have a pretty good narrative for questions about your weakness:
"My biggest weakness is X, i know because I solicited feedback from my colleagues and Y what they said. To address this problem I have started to do Z in alignment with my manager, and I am starting to see the improvement already."
If you tell a story like that, you make it clear that you are a person that actively seeks to improve on their weaknesses and that the problem is already under control.
Addendum:
There is another reason to ask the question where the weakness is important. While it is clear that every candidate has some weaknesses, we don't know which ones.
Some weaknesses matter more than others given the team structure they will be embedded in.
If a candidate's weakness is lack of experience with incident handling, but the team's incident handling is pretty good and there is seniors that can mentor them, then the weakness is pretty important.
If the same candidate is meant to come in to a team who needs to improve on incident handling, it doesn't make sense to put them there.
For that reason it is important to be honest about the weakness, because you don't want to join in a situation where you are setup to fail.

Answer the 'weakness' question with a strength aligned with the position.
E.g, for a development job, "I'm very detailed oriented, but when I get in the mode, I don't want to be disturbed for hours". For Sales, "I'm a loud person, and some have said that I'm too persistent". For Accounts, "I have been known to spend too long searching for that perfect reconciliation of the books. I balance this by checking with my manager to see what accuracy is required"
